# htaccess rewrite rule /en/support/my-tickets/ to my-tickets.php page

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to write rules for seo friendly links in htaccess, but I have a problems.

All my pages are situated in same root folder

- css/ (folder)
- js/ (folder)
- includes/ (folder with vocabularies and config.php file)
- *index.php*
- *support.php*
- *new-ticket.php*
- *all-tickets.php*
- *my-profile.php*

Links that are constructed .com/language/page - Works fine!

eg.   /en/  (it is index.php?lang=en)

eg.   /fr/my-profile/    (it is (my-profile.php?lang=fr)

eg.   /en/support/

What I am trying to do is to make: 
/en/support/new-ticket/ 
/en/support/all-tickets/

And I don't know how to make it right. It redirect me everytime to support.php page.
.htaccess code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+\.php)\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/(.+?)/?$ /$2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/?$ /?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/^support$/?$ /$3?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: What is internal rewrite URI for `/en/support/new-ticket/`. Is it just `/support.php?lang=en` leaving `new-ticket` out?

Comment: for internal it will be /new-ticket.php?lang=en. But I need to show it in link bar as /en/support/new-ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last rule doesn't appear correct. Change that to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/support/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I thought that it will not work, but it worked after I put this rule above other rules!

Comment: Yes I forgot to remind you about the placement of this rule. It should be placed just below `R=301` rule.